# How to order this tricky PHP associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, sorting

How to order this tricky PHP associative array?

I have this associative array:

```
Array (
    [4] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
```

I need to order it by key with highest value, BUT I also need to keep the keys with the same values in their original order, so it needs to come out to:

```
Array (
    [2] => 4
    [4] => 3
    [3] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [1] => 1
    )
```

I cannot use arsort() because it rearranges the keys with the same value based on the key's numeric order, I'm really at a loss here! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[natsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) to rescue:

```
$blub = array(4 => 3, 2 => 4, 3 => 1, 6 => 1, 1 => 1);
natsort($blub);
$blub = array_reverse($blub, true);

var_dump($blub);
```

This will always output:

```
array(5) { [2]=> int(4) [4]=> int(3) [3]=> int(1) [6]=> int(1) [1]=> int(1) }
```

natsort seems to be using a different sorting algorithm which luckily preserves the order when the values are the same as opposed to asort. Note however that natsort *might* be slightly slower than the other traditional sorting functions because of this.